# SQL Query with session parameter in asp net does not work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to make some ASP.NET project and I've got some SQL query which I want to use to show data from my database but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I need to use my session parameter named "PESEL" as parameter in my query.(I'm using PESEL as primary key in one table in my SQL database as login and in another table as FK to link the tables). The problem is that: In the database, the column is of the varchar type. I need to compare the value of my session with the value in my database, please tell me what should I modify in the query below so it could work properly.

If you need any data to analyze my problem please let me know. Any help is very appreciated.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="WizytyPacjentow" runat="server"
                     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WizytaConnectionString %>"
                     SelectCommand="SELECT WIZYTA.PESEL, Pacjenci.Imię + ' ' + Pacjenci.Nazwisko AS [dane pacjenta], WIZYTA.data AS [data wizyty], WIZYTA.godzina, Personel.Nazwisko + ' ' + Personel.Imię + '-' + Personel.Stanowisko AS lekarz FROM Pacjenci INNER JOIN Personel ON Pacjenci.PESEL = Personel.PESEL INNER JOIN WIZYTA ON Personel.IdPracownika = WIZYTA.IdPracownika WHERE (WIZYTA.PESEL = @Param)">
                <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter  Name="Param" SessionField="PESEL" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: I receive communicate "No data was returned." but when i do Query select * from Wizyta there is 20 records already. Is it possible because of that i don't have any records in table Personel ? Shouldn't it show just empty header ?

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler and get the executed query from your web site to the SQL Server

Comment: Yes, when i do that it shows me only header. I execute query in Visual Studio 2013.Do You mean SQL Server Profiler ? Honestly I have never used that tool before.

Comment: Hep I mean that tool. use it and check if the request sent to the server is correct

Comment: Would be so kind and tell me how can i use this tool to check my request ?

Comment: This video will hep you on that => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJ8Dyv4Uk6E

Comment: Query like that below works fine:        
SELECT WIZYTA.PESEL, Pacjenci.Imię + ' ' + Pacjenci.Nazwisko AS [dane pacjenta], WIZYTA.data AS [data wizyty], WIZYTA.godzina, Personel.Nazwisko + ' ' + Personel.Imię + '-' + Personel.Stanowisko AS lekarz FROM Pacjenci INNER JOIN Personel ON Pacjenci.PESEL = Personel.PESEL INNER JOIN WIZYTA ON Personel.IdPracownika = WIZYTA.IdPracownika WHERE (WIZYTA.PESEL = '93012300123');

Comment: It works with SQL when i define specific param. When i'm using session param it does not work.